# Is there any way to compact this redundant code?

Tags: css

Currently, my stylesheet has this in it:

```css
.form-control {
  background-color: #23272A;
  border-color: #23272A;
}

.form-control:focus {
  background-color: #23272A;
  border-color: #23272A;
}

.form-control:disabled {
  background-color: #23272A;
  border-color: #23272A;
}
```

So, I was wondering if there is any way to combine these, essentially to point the three states into one collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there is, put the 3 rules all in one rule, using the 3 selectors at the same time separated by comma, given all the selectors have the same properties

```css
.form-control,
.form-control:focus,
.form-control:disabled {
  background-color: #23272A;
  border-color: #23272A;
}
```

Comment: It's not just a matter of compact code, it also helps to maintain it in the future.